# Sqlcl - Error Message = no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path

Tags: sqlcl

I set the below environment variables and running below command from sqlcl,

sql $ABC_DB_PROD_USERNAME/$ABC_DB_PROD_PASSWORD@"$ABC_DB_PROD_TNS"

I am getting Error Message = no ocijdbc18 in java.library.path

I have no idea what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution i.e set the environment variable with escape character of '\' before all the braces of '(' , that was giving above error. when i removed '\' from environment variable values, its solved.